# How to increase performance of booting?

Tags: 12.10, boot

I am experiencing slow booting sequence from 12.10.

Only chromium browser is selected for startup and it does enable automatically under startup applications.

I try to restart and it may take 15 seconds to complete booting sequence. Before, it was much faster.

Any suggestion to increase booting performance?

Answer (score 5):

I got it.

Just made hidden startup items to be visible from startup applications and I was able to deselect the auto running apps. Now the OS is booting faster.

Command:

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

This helped me to enable hidden items to be displayed.